# A function that stores inputed integers in a stack and reverses them without duplicate sequences

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying write a function which reads "num" of integers, stores all integers in a stack and prints them in reverse order. However, if consecutive numbers are the same, only one of them will be stored in the stack.

this is what I've come up with so far but I'm not quite getting what I want.

```
def read_integers(num):
    s = Stack()
    count = 0
    string = ""
    for i in range(num):
        int_str = input("Enter an integer:")
        if int_str != string:
            string += int_str
            s.push(int_str)
            count += 1


    for i in range(count-1):
        print(s.pop())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably `string += int_str` try changing it to `string = int_str`.

The issue is that you are building up integers in your string.

```
string = ""     # initially
string = "1"    # after first input
string = "12"   # after second input
```

Now unless you type `12` as the next input the next string will be appended.

Also since you are only looping over `count-1` at the end of the function you are not printing the bottom number in the stack.

There might also be a problem with your read loop since if you want to read four numbers and one of the users inputs is rejected then only three values will be stored in the stack.